# Creating a CSS Inside Border on One Side

Tags: html, css, border

How can I produce the effect of a border on the *inside* of one side of my element?

My goal is to create a marker that indicates the currently selected item from a vertical list. Such as in the mockup below, where the 3rd item is selected:

[image]

Because this is a updatable state, which I'm setting by giving the `li` tag a `class="active"`, I have been going down the path of the `::after` pseudo-element.

The closest I have gotten is the following :

```
ul li::after {
        background-color: #fbc123;
        content: "";
        float: right;
        height: 40px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 5px; }
```

This is still putting the highlight on the outside of the 40px-by-40px box. How can I shift this, 5 pixels to the right?

I have create a jsFiddle, but it is behaving differently then what I see in my real code. In the jsFiddle the yellow lines remain on the left, instead of the aligning to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/m8A3e/

How can I create the effect of the 5px border on the right side only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

http://jsfiddle.net/m8A3e/1/

First of all I removed the float because floats and `position: absolute;` can't be used together. Then I gave the li relative positioning and gave the marker the proper top/right positions.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can just try using `border-right`, set the `relative` position for the inner direct child and send them to the back using `z-index` like this:

```
ul > li.active {
  border-right:5px solid yellow;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
ul > li.active > * {
  position:relative;
  z-index:-3;
}
```

You don't need to use pseudo-element at all. Here is the [working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/m8A3e/2/)

Look closely to the above demo, the right border seems to be zigzaged a little at the end (because of the top and left borders). You can try using inset `box-shadow` instead for better result:

```
ul > li.active {        
  box-shadow:-5px 0 yellow inset;
}
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/m8A3e/3/)

**NOTE**: if you have some inline element (like the `a` element) as the most direct child (and fill the parent space), you should set style `display:block` for that element, otherwise it will seem to be hidden after being applied the style `position:relative`.

Comment: Interesting! I put this in my real code and the contents of the `li` have disappeared - I have a `<a href=""><img ...></a>` in the real code. I'm looking fixing that as I like the simplicity of the `box-shadow`!

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey looks like you set some position-related style for the content, this approach of course has its own limit.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey ah, I've found it, you can set the selector `ul > li.active * ` instead of `ul > li.active > *`. Or you could also set the style for the `a` tag as `display:block`, it's required to make it not disappear.

Comment: It actually appears to be a background color I have set on the parent container. http://jsfiddle.net/EvilClosetMonkey/m8A3e/4/ - notice the blue showing through on the active block. I'm looking into alternative styling to avoid this.

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey I'm sorry for that approach, looks like it has more problems than I thought. To solve the problem you pointed in the comment, we also have to set the `position:relative` for the `container` and set the `z-index` properly. However the **hardest** remaining problem is the content is sent behind the `li`, you can still see the content because of the `li`'s background being  `transparent` but you can't interact with the content (clicking, hovering, ...) I've tried using `pointer-events` but no luck. I've found another tweak with `clip`: http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/m8A3e/6/

Comment: Anyway, maybe using the pseudo-element has its own advantage.